# How do i write the classic high/low game in F#?

Tags: f#

I was reading up on functional languages and i wondered how i would implement 'tries' in a **pure** functional language. So i decided to try to do it in F#

But i couldnt get half of the basics. I couldnt figure out how to use a random number, how to use return/continue (at first i thought i was doing a multi statement if wrong but it seems like i was doing it right) and i couldnt figure out how to print a number in F# so i did it in the C# way.

Harder problems is the out param in tryparse and i still unsure how i'll do implement `tries` without using a mutable variable. Maybe some of you guys can tell me how i might correctly implement this

C# code i had to do last week

```
using System;

namespace CS_Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var tries = 0;
            var answer = new Random().Next(1, 100);
            Console.WriteLine("Guess the number between 1 and 100");
            while (true)
            {
                var v = Console.ReadLine();
                if (v == "q")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("you have quit");
                    return;
                }
                int n;
                var b = Int32.TryParse(v, out n);
                if (b == false)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("This is not a number");
                    continue;
                }
                tries++;
                if (n == answer)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Correct! You win!");
                    break;
                }
                else if (n < answer)
                    Console.WriteLine("Guess higher");
                else if (n > answer)
                    Console.WriteLine("Guess lower");
            }
            Console.WriteLine("You guess {0} times", tries);
            Console.WriteLine("Press enter to exist");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

The very broken and wrong F# code

```
open System;

let main() =
    let tries = 0;
    let answer = (new Random()).Next 1, 100
    printfn "Guess the number between 1 and 100"
    let dummyWhileTrue() =
        let v = Console.ReadLine()
        if v = "q" then
            printfn ("you have quit")
            //return
        printfn "blah"
        //let b = Int32.TryParse(v, out n)
        let b = true;
        let n = 3
        if b = false then
            printfn ("This is not a number")
            //continue;
        //tries++
        (*
        if n = answer then
            printfn ("Correct! You win!")
            //break;
        elif n < answer then
            printfn ("Guess higher")
        elif n>answer then
            printfn ("Guess lower")
        *)
    dummyWhileTrue()
    (Console.WriteLine("You guess {0} times", tries))
    printfn ("Press enter to exist")
    Console.ReadLine()
main()
```

Comment: "i wondered how i would implement 'tries'". Beware tries is the name of a data structure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Welcome to F#!

Here's a working program; explanation follows below.

```
open System

let main() = 
    let answer = (new Random()).Next(1, 100)
    printfn "Guess the number between 1 and 100" 
    let rec dummyWhileTrue(tries) = 
        let v = Console.ReadLine() 
        if v = "q" then 
            printfn "you have quit"
            0
        else
            printfn "blah" 
            let mutable n = 0
            let b = Int32.TryParse(v, &n) 
            if b = false then 
                printfn "This is not a number"
                dummyWhileTrue(tries)
            elif n = answer then 
                printfn "Correct! You win!"
                tries
            elif n < answer then 
                printfn "Guess higher"
                dummyWhileTrue(tries+1) 
            else // n>answer
                printfn "Guess lower"
                dummyWhileTrue(tries+1) 
    let tries = dummyWhileTrue(1) 
    printfn "You guess %d times" tries
    printfn "Press enter to exit"
    Console.ReadLine()  |> ignore
main()
```

A number of things...

If you're calling methods with multiple arguments (like `Random.Next`), use parens around the args (`.Next(1,100)`).

You seemed to be working on a recursive function (`dummyWhileTrue`) rather than a while loop; a while loop would work too, but I kept it your way.  Note that there is no `break` or `continue` in F#, so you have to be a little more structured with the `if` stuff inside there.

I changed your `Console.WriteLine` to a `printfn` to show off how to call it with an argument.

I showed the way to call `TryParse` that is most like C#.  Declare your variable first (make it mutable, since `TryParse` will be writing to that location), and then use `&n` as the argument (in this context, `&n` is like `ref n` or `out n` in C#).  Alternatively, in F# you can do like so:

```
let b, n = Int32.TryParse(v)
```

where F# lets you omit trailing-out-parameters and instead returns their value at the end of a tuple; this is just a syntactic convenience.

`Console.ReadLine` returns a string, which you don't care about at the end of the program, so pipe it to the `ignore` function to discard the value (and get rid of the warning about the unused string value).

Comment: Thank you! this was very informative. At first i was disappointed to see tries being returned because i was hoping to learn how to how to manage multiple variables being modified but then your clear tryparse tuple showed me how! thanks again. I'm really liking this answer. Everything looks pure functional to me (after updating the way tryparse is used)

Answer (score 6):

Here's my take, just for the fun:

```
open System

let main() = 
    let answer = (new Random()).Next(1, 100)
    printfn "Guess the number between 1 and 100" 
    let rec TryLoop(tries) = 
        let doneWith(t) = t
        let notDoneWith(s, t) = printfn s; TryLoop(t) 
        match Console.ReadLine() with
        | "q" -> doneWith 0
        | s -> 
            match Int32.TryParse(s) with
            | true, v when v = answer -> doneWith(tries)
            | true, v when v < answer -> notDoneWith("Guess higher", tries + 1) 
            | true, v when v > answer -> notDoneWith("Guess lower", tries + 1)
            | _ -> notDoneWith("This is not a number", tries)

    match TryLoop(1) with
        | 0 -> printfn "You quit, loser!"
        | tries -> printfn "Correct! You win!\nYou guessed %d times" tries

    printfn "Hit enter to exit"
    Console.ReadLine()  |> ignore
main()
```

Things to note:

- Pattern matching is prettier, more concise, and - I believe - more idiomatic than nested ifs
- Used the tuple-return-style `TryParse` suggested by Brian
- Renamed `dummyWhileTrue` to `TryLoop`, seemed more descriptive
- Created two inner functions `doneWith` and `notDoneWith`, (for purely aesthetic reasons)

Answer (score 5):

I lifted the main pattern match from `Evaluate` in @Huusom's solution but opted for a recursive loop and accumulator instead of @Hussom's (very cool) discriminate union and application of Seq.unfold for a very compact solution.

```
open System
let guessLoop answer = 
    let rec loop tries =
        let guess = Console.ReadLine()
        match Int32.TryParse(guess) with
        | true, v when v < answer -> printfn "Guess higher." ; loop (tries+1)
        | true, v when v > answer -> printfn "Guess lower." ; loop (tries+1)
        | true, v -> printfn "You won." ; tries+1
        | false, _ when guess = "q" -> printfn "You quit." ; tries
        | false, _ -> printfn "Not a number." ; loop tries
    loop 0

let main() =
    printfn "Guess a number between 1 and 100."
    printfn "You guessed %i times" (guessLoop ((Random()).Next(1, 100)))
```

Answer (score 3):

Also for the fun of if:

```
open System

type Result =
    | Match
    | Higher
    | Lower
    | Quit
    | NaN

let Evaluate answer guess =
    match Int32.TryParse(guess) with
    | true, v when v < answer -> Higher
    | true, v when v > answer -> Lower
    | true, v -> Match
    | false, _ when guess = "q" -> Quit
    | false, _ -> NaN

let Ask answer =
    match Evaluate answer (Console.ReadLine()) with
    | Match -> 
        printfn "You won."
        None
    | Higher -> 
        printfn "Guess higher."
        Some (Higher, answer)
    | Lower -> 
        printfn "Guess lower."
        Some (Lower, answer)
    | Quit -> 
        printfn "You quit."
        None
    | NaN ->
        printfn "This is not a number."
        Some (NaN, answer)

let main () = 
    printfn "Guess a number between 1 and 100."
    let guesses = Seq.unfold Ask ((Random()).Next(1, 100))
    printfn "You guessed %i times" (Seq.length guesses)

let _ = main()
```

I use an enumeration for state and Seq.unfold over input to find the result.

Comment: The `Some` is messing with my head. I dont think Some is like a 'this function' but that is how you appear to use it. Where does some get its type?

Comment: @Huusom, I really like this answer, but the guesses are being under-counted by 1

Comment: Some is defined in Option 'a. Either you have Some data (of type 'a) or you have None :)

Comment: @Stephen - sorry about that :) I only had the lunch break at work.

Comment: You could switch Result and Evaluate into an active pattern, but I'm not sure if it would significantly improve readability.

Comment: @Huusom, one other issue, NaN gets counted as a try, which is different from the OP's C# original answer. But again, I think your use of Seq.unfold is awesome here.